# Box-shadow of button is wider than the button itself

Tags: css

Hope somebody can help me. I've added custom css to a button but the shadow displayed is wider than the button itself:

This is how it looks:

[image]

This is the css:

```
.dip-button-dark-bg {
    border-radius: 5px !important;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #484848 !important;
}
```

Can someone tell me what I should add? I've been searching for a solution for 2 hours now and have become pretty desperate.

Comment: Please show us your `HTML` code as well.

Comment: Can you include the HTML too? It looks like the button consists of multiple layers. Try putting the box-shadow on the same element that has the border.

Comment: Check this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muhammad_Usman/eawv8qqa/). I think you have duplicated class `.dip-button-dark-bg` on parent of button as well. Check your `HMTL` for necessary corrections.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The buttons can be found at https://digital-power.com/data-analist-inhuren/.

Comment: I can't easily find the css of the button since it's a pre-developed button as part of a Wordpress theme (Jupiter by Artbees). In the cms I have to select an existing button and can apply custom css to it. I'm currently using the 'flat' button by Jupiter/Visual Composer..